# How can i build a excel sheet from thousands of registers with good performance?

Tags: java, loading

I have about one million of registers and our team is developing the export functionality of these registers to excel.

We were using hibernate to catch a thousand registers each time and writing at file.

Even so, this was very expensive and slow. The user  ericbn advised me to use JDBC instead Hibernate, nevertheless, wasn't sufficient to decrease time.

I tried the classical approach, retrieving data and putting into excel files using the library HSSFWorkbook.

Is there an other approach that i could follow?

Any help is valid.

Here is my code:

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response)throws IOException  {


    String inputFile="";
    if (request.getParameter("eventID") != null) {
        inputFile = request.getParameter("eventID").toString();
    }

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","user","pass");

        stmt =conn.createStatement();

        String strQuery = "select * from table where eventId like '%"+ inputFile +"%'" ;

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);


        HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

        HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 2);
        rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("sno");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("employeeID");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("projectName");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("employeeName");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("designation");
        rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("hasAttended");

        int index = 3;
        int sno = 0;
        String name = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            sno++;

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) index);
            row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(sno);
            row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString(10));
            row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString(7));
            row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString(11));
            row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString(8));
            row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getString(4));
            index++;

        }

        String filename = "ViewAttendees.xls";
        response.setProperty("application/x-excel","");
        response.addProperty("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

        OutputStream os =response.getPortletOutputStream(); 
        hwb.write(os);
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error: "+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour and try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what i've tried was a basic get register from the DB and put it into file, as a string buffer.

Comment: Not using Hibernate, but JDBC directly, can be an option to improve the performance.

Comment: Ok, but we have tried this too, and it wasn't sufficient, because the performance was slow yet.
Have an other way to improve it?

And why the downvote? It's a technique asking, i did ommitted the code because it  was very simple (just get and put data into file)

Comment: inserting code and clarifying the question, i think now it's more clear to anyone understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that what you call a `register` I call a `cell`.

If you have an excel spreadsheet with thousands of cells, and you want good performance, you can't use an excel spreadsheet.  That is because an excel spreadsheet is a tool built for *many* possible computations, and you are only using *one* of the possible computations.

Since you are using hibernate, I know that you are using Java.  I am also going to guess that you are using a relational database, because that is what hibernate is build to do.  So, I think you are pulling your data out of a relational database (like Oracle, MySQL, PostGres, or Microsoft SQL Server).  If I am wrong, then don't pay too much attention to the next paragraph.

If you data is coming from a database, and you are writing it to a spreadsheet, then you need to order the data retrieval from the database so you don't have to load all of the data into memory before writing some of it out to the spreadsheet.  This might mean selecting the first thousand cells from the database and writing them, and then the next thousand, and so on.  This prevents your program from using too much memory, which can create certain kinds of performance problems.

The real key to solving a performance problem is not which tools you use, but identifying which part of the program is using the scarce resource.  For some, time is the scarce resource, for others it is memory, and for others it is something else.  Good performance is knowing which resources you cannot use more of, and which resources you can use more of.  You might trade memory for time, or time for disk space, etc.

Once you can identify which part of your program is too slow, there are two techniques:

1. If the slow part is used a lot, use it less.
2. Speed up the slow part.

Unfortunately, with the wording of your question, this is probably the best answer you are going to get.

Good Luck!

PS. Virtualization only helps if the problem is that you don't have enough "real" items, but the real items can be substituted with "fake" ones.  If you swap fake "registers" with fake "registers" then you probably won't get any improvement.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i have thinking if the good way may be use some threads, where each thread gets a amount of data(e.g. a thousand) and writes in the file.

Maybe an other way is write in many sheets where each thread writes in the sheets, and finally, i can put these files in one big sheet or put all sheets in one zipfile.

What do you think about theses options? Is a good and viable option?

+1 for your answer :)

Comment: @RaulSenaFerreira If you don't measure the parts of your program, and identify which part is the slow part, you are only going to make the fast parts faster.  Making a fast part faster when the slow parts are still slow is a waste of time and money.  If you make the fast step (10% of your program time) 100% faster, you sped up the program by 5%.  If you make the slow step (90% of your program) 100%  faster, you sped up the program by 45%.  Don't waste your time, find the slow step (the bottleneck) before you try to make anything faster.

Comment: @RaulSenaFerreira You can if you want, but remember that a few down votes don't even make up for a single upvote.  Just work on the answer to make it more clear, and eventually someone will find it because they have a similar problem, and then they'll upvote it.  It is hard to get points long-term if you kill the stuff that is downvoted, because you have less "stuff" out there to eventually get an upvote here and there.